# jquery fileuploader in firefox sends query too long

Tags: jquery, firefox, jquery-file-upload

I use https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload for ajax-uploads. As described, there must be no troubles for file <4GB

All the tests I had on localhost, so there is no network-transfer delays

10mb file uploads immediately, as good as 100mb and 200mb files (in FF)

300mb+ file never uploads! Breakpoint on server-side handler is never used

It is not server-side trouble, because there are no problems in Opera and Chrome, and I tested 2 different handlers (PHP and node.js)

Is it possible to do something with fileupload configuration? (Without using chunked uploads)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was solved after firefox update. I still dont know what was the reason, but it looks like it was a browser bug